# Debug Apache mod_status showing 151 requests/sec - 2.7 GB/second

Tags: apache-2.2

One of my web servers went crazy this morning and showed "151 requests/sec - 2.7 GB/second - 140.7 MB/request" the normal is like "11.1 requests/sec - 65.6 kB/second - 5.9 kB/request"

I don't even think that kind of through put is possible on my server. It was also listing odd symbols for the urls and the amount of data transfered for connections was off the meter

```
246-0  -1286402072  0/0/0  ?  0.00  -1444841118  0  -5416403825852416.0  0.00  0.00    °Rk³  
247-0  18  0/0/0  ?  -13112985.76  2094967848  0  -5428200825946112.0  0.00  0.00      
248-2  23437  0/0/2  _  0.00  0  0  0.0  0.00  -5340330065920.00  74.53.23.134  web2.mydomain.com  OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0
249-2  23279  0/2981898840/0  W  16673317.60  11  0  0.0  2844.06  0.00  201.144.221.245  www.mydomain.com  GET /cb8ff49a2395a7b1accbbce1e4cf164f/view/256 HTTP/1.1
250-0  0  40600/3009863336/0  ?  3816369.92  910209710  0  2913775.3  -5323551899648.00  -5324315849947.28  èøÏ²
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before and know what might be causing it?

I posted the full mod_status output here http://pastie.org/916066

Comment: I think I should have asked the question "How do I debug a busy apache server running lots of custom php code?"

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a recursive 404 on a page that isn't hit frequently?